# How can I find and print only specific information

Tags: regex, bash, awk, capturing-group

I'm trying to have awk print only a specific information. I can make it when it comes only to simple text strings. But its not working when I ask to search and print something like:

```
/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-99]*\.[0-999]*/
```

I'm looking for numbers separated by dots, almost like IP address. For example:

```
#.#.#.##.### where #=integer
```

For example:

This prints only `TEXT` and works fine.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==“TEXT”){print $i} } }' source.txt > result.txt
```

This should print what I need, but doesn't work.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==“/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-99]*\.[0-999]*/”){print $i} } }' source.txt > result.txt
```

This works fine but prints the whole line, and not only what I need:

```
awk -F"\t" '/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-99]*\.[0-999]*/{ print }' source.txt > result.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `==` compares two strings, it doesn't do a regexp match.  For that you want `~`. And you also want to remove the quotes around the regexp. Like this: `awk 'BEGIN { if ("a.c" ~ /a\.*/) print "yes"; else print "no" }'`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Did it and worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Was using "==" instead of "~" and unnecessary quotes.

This is working fine:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-99]*\.[0-999]*/){print $i} } }' jfinancas.txt > teste5.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you using regexp like [0-9]* - I mean why '*' ? meaning you are looking for any number (including zero) of digits ? [0-9]  is enough. If you want multiple repetitions but finite, just repeat : /[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]/ for  #.#.#.##.###

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) \
{ if($i ~ /[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/){print $i} } }' jfinancas.txt > teste5.txt
```

Using gawk (gnu awk), you can manage repetitions within regexp [0-9]{3} will match 3 digits exactly.

Comment: To be honest, my knowledge is very limited and im using '*' because it was included in a code i found to be helpful for me. If i dont need to use it, fine, lets remove it and make the code more clear. Im looking for numbers formatted as described in the initial question. Thus, the first 3 numbers can be anything from 1 to 9; the 4 number can be anything from 01 to 99 and the 5 number anything from 001 to 999. Ex.: 2.4.9.76.090

Comment: no issue ;) - but [0-99] does not mean 'match any number between 0 & 99", [0-999] means match any character between '0' and '9', the [] defines a set of characters, and the - means an interval between 2 characters.

Comment: If i have more than 1 instance of that information in the same line, is there a way to tell the command to print only 1 instance of that information for every line?

Comment: Your loop go through each & every field and check if this field complies with your pattern. So you just have to break your look at first match.

Comment: Alright, so in this case could i also specify the code to go through only a certain field in each line? Because this info would be only in a certain field of the line, not all of them.

Comment: correct, change {print $i} to {print $i; break} and your loop will stops; awk will then process the next line.